# Packet Details Markup Language

Tags: c#-4.0, network-programming, gsm

I have problem in parsing XML containing gsm packets through my .Net application.I want to decode data obtained from parsed XML as wire shark Decode.Problem is,That my information regarding gsm packets and protocols is limited.

I read somewhere that wire shark parse xml through PDML(Packet Details Markup Language) File which contains all the information of all types of protocols including gsm.

I googled but not found that file.

Any help and Suggestions will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Export->XML menu in Wireshark to generate a PDML file. PDML is an XML representation of your the captured data flow. For this to work, you should have the GSM dissectors installed along with Wireshark.

[GSM call flows](http://www.eventhelix.com/realtimemantra/telecom/) will give you an idea on what to expect from the decoded Wireshark output.